# icmp packets appearing with udp packets

Tags: udp

[image]

I am sending udp packets from one pc to other. I am observing the traffic on wireshark on the pc where I am receiving udp packets. One interesting thing I see is icmp packets appearing suddenly. Then they disappear and again appear in a cyclic manner. What can be the reason for this. Am I doing some thing wrong. And what bad effects can it have on my udp reception performance.

Please also find the attached wireshark figure taken from the destination pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ICMP packets are created by the other host because the UDP port is not open. The ICMP packet includes the first X bytes of the packet that was dropped so the sender can read out which session was affected.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So it means that the sender is doing its job fine. But at the receiver end the destined udp port is not open, resulting in icmp packets to go from destination to source pc. right ? What I am doing is that I am just sending packets form the source to destination computer on a random udp port. Can you please tell me that how can I reserve a udp port on the destination computer where I can receive packets from source computer so that there are no icmp. Thanks again :)

Comment: The easiest way is to use netcat: `netcat -vulp 12345` where `12345` is the portnumber

Comment: super. Bästa hälsningar från Sverige